# Using Multiple View Controllers

Tags: swift, xcode

I know this is a beginner question. When I click on Main Storyboard it shows two View Controllers connected by a button [click here for picture (circled is the storyboard I am trying to code for and on the right is what shows up when I click assistant)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/top9a.png). When I open assistant it shows this long lengthy code that I did not write. How do I add code for the second view controller? I have tried making a separate storyboard but that is too tedious and not very helpful for what I am trying to achieve. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press `Ctrl + N` and create new Cocoa Touch Class where you select UIViewController and set a name for your new controller class. This will create your new controller. Then go into your storyboad, make sure you have opened right tab, click on view controller, press `Command + Option + 4` and on the right write name of your new viewcontroller class to a class field.

You asked very basic question, where you lack any effort of searching answer by yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am a new user to stack overflow.